# html link to css isnt showing styles

Tags: css, asp.net, external

[Screenshot of network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUOkk.png) My external css isn't displaying the styles. I have a link in my html but I think the CSS may not be working. Do I need to add additional elements to my style sheet to get the displays to work properly?

```
.responsive {
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.simple-subscription-form {
    background: #000000;
    color: #94C60D;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0;
    align-content: center
}

.simple-subscription-form.button {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

#dialog-message {
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto
}

div.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the related html ?

Comment: please add a screenshot of your network tab in devtools

Comment: stack overflow won't let me add it, says I have too much code when I try

Comment: we only need the part where it imports the css (link tag)

Comment: And you have some problem with you mapping in asp.net. The css can't be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the file system. Use your project resource folder.

Use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Resources/PATH + FILENAME">`

Comment: Yup, turns out it wasn't linked properly